# Proxy pass an application from a different machine to an apache web server

Tags: apache2.4

> I have three applications running, 2 on local machine/server where Apache is installed and 1 on a different machine/server.
>   I am using Apache2.4 on Ubuntu 18.04

```
application 1(yii) = 127.0.0.1:80 
application 2(mantis bt) = 127.0.0.1:8080
application 3(yii) = 192.168.X.X:80
```

I want to configure my apache web server to host the three applications on https. I proxy pass both app2 and app3.

```
app2 = /app2 http://127.0.0.1:8080
app3 = /app3 http://192.168.X.X
```

app1 can be accessed successfully without error,
app2  and app3 can be accessed but .css, .js and other files cannot be found and error 404.

Note: I can access all three apps when not on proxy pass.

also it is possible to host the three apps and have a url like the following:
    https://app1.example
    https://app2.example
    https://app2.example

I am new to apache. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure apache virtual host as a below configuration

> For app2

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
     ServerName app2.domain.com
     ServerAdmin youremail@email.com

     ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/
     ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</Virtualhost *:80>
```

> For app3

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
     ServerName app3.domain.com
     ServerAdmin youremail@email.com

     ProxyPass http://192.168.X.X/
     ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.X.X/
</Virtualhost *:80>
```

Create a separate virtual host for both domains.

After creating virtual host restart apache

```
service apache2 restart
```

It's working for me, I hope it will be worked for you and load .css, .js and other files.

> If you want to redirect aap3 to https, then your final virtual host file will be like below configuration:

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
     ServerName app2.domain.com
     ServerAdmin youremail@email.com

     ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/
     ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</Virtualhost *:80>

<Virtualhost *:80>
     ServerName app3.domain.com
     Redirect / https://app3.domain.com/
</Virtualhost *:80>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName app3.domain.com
     ServerAdmin youremail@email.com

     ProxyPass http://192.168.X.X/
     ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.X.X/

     Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
     ServerAlias app3.domain.com
     SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/app3.domain.com/fullchain.pem
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/app3.domain.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thank you so much @Subhash. now it's working. Now I have to redirect all access to my websites to https. do I have to make three <VirtualHost *:443/> too? or is there a way to redirect all of them in one configuration? thank you.

Comment: @carlbasabe https://www.serverkaka.com/2017/12/how-to-configure-ssl-in-apache-linux.html

Comment: Hi @Subhash, I have another question, as I have said in my setup I have two machines, they are sharing on 1 Public IP, when I try to redirect all access to app3 (the one I proxy_pass) to https, the page showing is app1. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: @carlbasabe please check my answer I add configuration for app3 https redirection.

Comment: Hi @Subhash, I tried your config but it still not redirecting to https, do I have to edit the .htaccess of app3? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please check my config below:
 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app1
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/app1_log
    LogLevel debug

```
<Directory /var/www/html/app1>
AllowOverride none
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
# use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
</Directory>

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyVia Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
AddDefaultCharset off
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location /app2>
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/login_page.php
    ProxyPassReverse http://1127.0.0.1:8080/login_page.php
    SetEnv              proxy-sendchunks 1
</Location>

<Location /app3>
    ProxyPass http://192.168.X.X/
    ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.X.X/
    SetEnv              proxy-sendchunks 1
</Location>

<Location /static/>
   ProxyPass !
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSL Configuration
</VirtualHost>
```